# How do I style the td-elements in a table row upon dragging using jqueryui sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Using jQueryUI sortable I am able to drag and drop rows in a table.
I'd like to change the style of the row when dragging.

An option found on the internet is the following:

```
start: function(event, ui) {
    $(ui.item).css({
      'border': '1px solid #F95658',
      'background-color': '#bbb'
    });
  },
```

This however does not let me style the borders or the background color of the cells.

The same goes for the placeholder.

Is there a way to style these?

```js
$("table tbody").sortable({
  axis: 'y',
  placeholder: "ui-sortable-placeholder",
  revert: true,
  helper: fixHelper,
  start: function(event, ui) {
    $(ui.item).css({
      'border': '1px solid #F95658',
      'background-color': '#bbb'
    });
  },
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    $(ui.item).css({
      //'background-color': '#fff'
    });
  }
}).disableSelection();


var fixHelper = function(e, ui) {
  ui.children().each(function() {
    $(this).width($(this).width());
  });
  return ui;
};
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

th {
  background-color: #dce0e3;
}

.ui-sortable-placeholder {
  background-color: #fff;
  outline: 0px dashed black;
  padding: 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.17/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ernst Handel</td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus </td>
      <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari </td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Its working fine in Demo. It changes border color to red and background color to gray when dragging. Isn't it you want?

Comment: It does for the outer border, but not for the inner borders (TD left and right borders) nor does the background color of the TD items change.

Comment: Why not just add a class to the row and do it with css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this for TD

```
$(ui.item).find('td').css({
  'border': '1px solid #F95658',
  'background-color': '#bbb'
});
```

after this

```
$(ui.item).css({
  'border': '1px solid #F95658',
  'background-color': '#bbb'
});
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thnks Shaybi!